# Flask Postgresql psycopg2 - could not create socket: Too many open files

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a flask application on nginx + gunicorn with mod-wsgi.I am having is that I am running multiple threads in my python code in loop but I am making sure all the DB connections opened are also closed successfully. The only issue I am having is that I am getting error -

```
> (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not create socket: Too many open files

I have tried multiple things

**vi /etc/sysctl.conf**

    fs.file-max=500000

vim /etc/security/limits.conf

    *         hard    nofile      500000
    *         soft    nofile      500000
    root      hard    nofile      500000
    root      soft    nofile      500000
    postgres soft nofile 500000
    postgres hard  nofile 500000
    nginx       soft    nofile      500000
    nginx       hard    nofile      500000

SESSION_OPTIONS = {
    'autocommit': True,
    'autoflush': True
}
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    'poolclass':NullPool,
    'pool_recycle': 120,
    'pool_pre_ping': True
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app, engine_options=SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS, session_options=SESSION_OPTIONS)
But still getting the same error when my code is accessing the DB again and again.

Here is how I am running queries on my database, To insert I am using ORM Sqlalchemy - 
user_buy_sell = UserBuySell(app_name=self.app_name.lower(),username=self.user_id)
db.session.add(user_buy_sell)
db.session.flush()
db.session.close()

#and for regular select and update I am using - 
read_sql = f"""SELECT count(*) as TotalCount FROM additional_last_buy_ins WHERE                                         username='{str(parameters['username']).lower()}' and app_name='{app_name.lower()}' """
            self.logFile.logInFile(read_sql)
            result = db.engine.execute(read_sql)
            for res in result:
                totalCount = int(res['totalcount'])
                break
            result.close()

Can you please guide me where I am doing things wrong
```

Comment: nIt sounds like you may be opening connections but not closing them.  Please share your code that handles database connections.

Comment: hi @snakecharmerb, I have updated the code above, can you please check

Comment: Try calling `db.session.remove()` instead of `db.session.close()` - flask-sqlalchemy uses scoped sessions, and `.remove` is the way to close these.  If you are using mulitple threads, I'm not sure why you are using a `NullPool`?  A shared engine with the default pool would seem more efficient.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, Thanks I will use db.session.remove() instead of close. For the pool settings, can you explain what should I do? I am running a flask application via which an API is fired and runs various loops for several hours until some condition is met and then it exits. I am required to open multiple connections at once if that API is fired by lets say by 500 people? What settings should I do?